# Can anyone explain how Rails' instantiate mailer objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailer

I want to send mails from different accounts.
I load my default email account from initializer file:

```
if Rails.env != 'test'
    ....
    email_settings = YAML::load(File.open("#{Rails.root.to_s}/config/email.yml"))
    ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = email_settings[Rails.env].symbolize_keys unless email_settings[Rails.env].nil?
end
```

but for some mailers I want send mails from special account:

```
def self.sendAlert(subj, message)
    self.smtp_settings = YAML::load(File.open("#{Rails.root.to_s}/config/email_bot.yml"))[Rails.env].symbolize_keys
    system_error_report(subj, message).deliver
end

def system_error_report(subj, message)
    @message = message
    mail to: "estarshono@gmail.com", subject: subj
end
```

As you can see, account change lies in class function 'sendAlert'. Before I put it there I tried to do it in 'system_error_report', but it wouldn't work: self.smtp_settings alter works only in static class function. I don't understand why )
Can somebody clear the question?

Answer (score 0):

Set your smtp_settings in environment files, not initializers.
Don't change smtp_settings in Mailer classes, it will change settings for all mailers.
Change mailer settings per object instance:

```
smtp_settings = YAML::load(...)
mailer.delivery_method.settings.merge! smtp_settings
```

Consider moving YAML loaded file once into config, and then retrieve just config instead of loading files each time you call mailer methods.

Comment: (1) I don't want to expose my passwords and logins to public git servers, so I use YAML files, which are excluded from git tracking. (2) I just checked: change in mailer of ActionMailer::Base's subclass doesn't change ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings

Comment: You can use YAML files in environment files too.